# How do I create an instance of type array in 3rd party XML?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have written a simple C# Windows application to test a 3rd party web service.  Here are two of the fields from the generated Reference.cs

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)]
public PriceType Price
{
    get
    {
        return this.priceField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.priceField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("ExpectedPrice");
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Contact", Order = 5)]
public ContactType[] Contact
{
    get
    {
        return this.contactField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.contactField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Contact");
    }
}
```

I created the request object, and assigned a value to Price as follows:-

```
RequestServiceType myRequest = new RequestServiceType();

myRequest.Price = new Blah.PriceType();
myRequest.Price.GrossPrice = new Blah.AmountType();
myRequest.Price.GrossPrice.Value = 10M;
```

However

```
myRequest.Contact = new Blah.ContactType();
```

> Errors with 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'RequestServiceType.ContactType' to 'RequestServiceType.ContactType[]'.

`ContactType` is an array in the Reference.cs (`ContactType[]`).  How do I create an instance of `Contact` in `myRequest`?

Comment: You cannot have an array of Attributes.  Change from : XmlElementAttribute to : XmlElement

Comment: Thank you.  The web services are provided by an external 3rd party, and Reference.cs is auto-generated.

Comment: If they are autogenerated this is done from a schema that may have errors.

Comment: Thank you jdweng.  This schema is used by a lot of organisations. It's my programming that has errors.  I really need to sit with a subject expert and go through the logic (or lack of it). Are there any Land Registry experts in the house?

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicity casting?

myRequest.Contact = (Contact[])(new Blah.ContactType());

Comment: Thank you, but the IDE then shows 'cast is redundant'.  The potential fix is to remove the cast, which puts me back at square one.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is what is the issue here.

the error message clearly explains that you are trying to assign an instance of the object to the property when the property expects an array of that object.

This will crate an array containing one instance

```
myRequest.Contact = new []{ new Blah.ContactType() };
```

which is just syntatic sugar for

```
var contact = new new Blah.ContactType();
var array = new Blah.ContactType[1];
array[0] = contact;
myRequest.Contact = array;
```

Comment: Hi Nkosi.  I managed to sort it last week, but your example is more elegant.  Thank you.